# Spring Data Example.of to check Set on Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity like:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {

private String tester;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "my_entity_my_object",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "my_object_id") })
private Set<MyObject> myObject;
}

@Entity
class MyObject {
private String testAgain;
}
```

When a example is made like so:

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.setTester("123");

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setTestAgain("111")

myEntity.getMyObject.add(myObject);

myEntityRepository.findOne(Example.of(myEntity));
```

The example includes the Set but the actual query generated ignores it. Is there anyway to make the example also check the set on the object? I do not see any example of this anywhere in the documentation and I have not found anyone else that has run into this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to configure the type of relation, you would normally do this with annotations such as OneToMany / ManyToMany, etc...  Then annotate the fetch type to Eager and it should collect the Set

Comment: Sorry I missed that on the example. I have those set. The example just doesn't include them in the query.

Comment: Have you also set the fetch type?

Comment: I have the fetchType set to eager. I updated the question info to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
private String tester;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<MyObject> myObject;
}

@Entity
class MyObject {
private String testAgain;
@OneToMany
private MyEntity myEntity,
}
```

You should know the best/more appropriate relations to use regarding your design.

Comment: Sorry. I missed this on the post. I'll update it. But that should be configured correctly. The Example just does not include it.